# Salvar no Banco de dados com filtros

Tags: javascript, ajax, banco-de-dados

estou trabalhando em um projeto, que tenho que salvar uma foto no banco de dados com os filtros aplicados, porem ela só salva a original e com as do filtros dá "erro". Já foi criado uma coluna na tabela das imagens com o nome de "filter", segue o código que já fiz.

```
$("#ztier-savecopy").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveCopy", "Library")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    ID : @Model.ID,
                    JsonTools: JSON.stringify(lc.getSnapshot(['shapes'])),
                    Base64Image: lc.getImage().toDataURL(),
                    //NuResolutionWidth: $("#ztier-tools-container").attr("width").replace("px",""),
                    //NuResolutionHeight: $("#ztier-tools-container").attr("height").replace("px","")
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Sucesso");
                    $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Uma cópia da imagem foi salva com sucesso!");
                    $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Erro");
                    $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Não foi possível salvar uma cópia da imagem!");
                    $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });

        $("#ztier-savefilter").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveFilter", "Library")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    ID: @Model.ID,
                    Base64Image: lc.getImage().toDataURL(),
                    Filter: getValues(), 
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Sucesso");
                    $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Uma cópia da imagem foi salva com sucesso!");
                    $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Erro");
                    $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Não foi possível salvar uma cópia da imagem");
                    $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });,
```

Comment: Que erro dá? E o que faz a função getValues()?

Comment: é um erro avisando que não foi possivel salvar a foto e a função pega os valores dos filtros aplicados(brilho, contraste...etc)